# Arquivos não são alterados no servidor

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, ubuntu

Estamos com o seguinte problema, ao realizar o upload dos arquivos para um servidor linux ubuntu 14.04, as alterações realizadas nos arquivos não surtem efeito no servidor, apenas localmente, já verificamos o arquivo no servidor,  ele é alterado perfeitamente, mas na aplicação essa modificação não é apresentada, isso vai de arquivos PHP a HTML/CSS.

Já à realizamos algumas pesquisas e encontramos poucos casos parecidos, o exemplo do problema está nesse link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184722/apache-not-reading-changes-to-php-files onde foi sugerido algumas alterações no servidor, como a desativação do opcahce, o que já foi realizado e não resolveu o problema.

Alguém saberia como resolver esse problema.

Comment: vc usa algum framework?

Comment: Sim framework proprietário.

Comment: Nós temos essa mesma aplicação em um outro servidor, mas em outra área com um outro domínio,  e lá as alterações acontecem normalmente,

Comment: Como está a permissão para grupo das pastas que recebem os arquivos?